# Is the optical phase space the same thing as the Hilbert space $L²(R^2)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-optics

I have trouble figuring out what Hilbert space it is mathematically. It looks similar to $L²(R^2)$ where each state is a distribution of over all the quadratures $(q,p)$